# Mocking a dependent bean with QuarkusMock?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, quarkus

I have a `@QuarkusTest` in which I want to test a service (lets call it `ServiceA`) that I inject.
This service has dependency (lets call it `EventX` which is annotated with `@Dependent` (javax.enterprise.event.Event)
As experienced and also stated in the documentation, this is not supported by `@QuarkusMock`. (Bonus question: Why is that exactly?)

So I tried the following, despite this is not a fine way to go, as I alter the actual state of a bean:

```
@QuarkusTest
class Test{
  @Inject
  ServiceA serviceA;

  @Inject
  Event<X> eventX;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup(){
    serviceA.eventX = spy(eventX);
    doReturn(true).when(eventX).doSomething();
  }
}
```

When I now run a test on `serviceA` eventX seems to get overriden by the original bean. I assume this is because of the lazy cdi.

Is there a way, I can mock or spy a `@Dependent` bean in a clean way, without messing with the context to much?

Answer (score 0):

Beans annotated with the scope `@Singleton` or `@Dependent` cannot be mocked with QuarkusMock, as per the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/blog/mocking/) itself, as they are "pseudo-scoped".

A `@RequestScoped` should be useful for your need, right?